# QLabel color and separateur

Tags: qt

```
IplImage *img_lb = cvCloneImage(img_orig);

         QImage qt_img = IplImage2QImage(img_lb);

             QLabel label_3;

             // display on label
             ui->label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_img));
             // resize the label to fit the image
               ui->label_3->resize(ui->label_3->pixmap()->size());
            // ui->label_3->show();
```

`hi i use Qt creator i would like to play video in the size of declared size and not his size ,someone can help?this is my code

Comment: can you help pleaaaaaaase??how can i add color to QLabel? i use the label to show video

Comment: What picture are you talking about? Where do you want color? Background or text color?

Comment: sorry i can't add picture because i'm new membre my really problem is when i play video in QLabel the video is not showing with label size ,so haw can do? please help me

Comment: Your question is unclear, the title doesn't match the content.  Is this question about size or colour?

Comment: it's about size ,sorry for the title I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Image scaled to you Label size, Use

```
ui->label_3->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(qt_img).scaled(ui->label_3->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio));
```

This would make your pixmap perfectly fit to the Label while ignoring the aspect ratio. For more look [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaled).